# Get localized file (resource) names, as shown in Windows Explorer

Tags: powershell, windows-shell

I am looking for a PowerShell function like `Get-LocalizedName($FilePath)`, returning the localized name of a file or its filename if it is not localized. I know that the localized names are stored in the `LocalizedFileNames` section of the respective `desktop.ini` files, but usually as resource file pointers rather than clear names.

Example: For the **Administrative Tools** folder and the locale **de-DE**, I want the clear name **Windows-Verwaltungsprogramme** instead of `@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21762`.

I was not able to find such a function, and also was not successful in analyzing the attributes of `Get-ChildItem` or google a regarding solution.

Is there any such function that I could use from PowerShell (v7)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution for **Get-LocalizedName**, digging into 20 years old VBS code using GetDetailsOf:

```
function Get-LocalizedName {
    Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][string]$FilePath) 
    $ChildObj = Get-ChildItem $FilePath 
    $FldrName = $ChildObj.DirectoryName 
    $FileName = $ChildObj.Name 
    $Shell    = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application 
    $Folder   = $Shell.Namespace($FldrName) 
    $File     = $Folder.ParseName($FileName) 
    return $($Folder.GetDetailsOf($File,0))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works for **folders** only. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72711704/7571258) for a solution that works for files, localized via `LocalizedFileNames` section of `Desktop.ini`.

---

This can be done using the [`Shell.Application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell) COM object:

```sh
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

# Get full path to the admin tools folder
$adminToolsPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('AdminTools')

# Get the shell folder corresponding to this path
if( $folder = $shell.NameSpace( $adminToolsPath ) ) {
    $folder.Title  # Output localized title
}

# Alternative:
if( $folder = $shell.NameSpace( [Environment+SpecialFolder]::AdminTools ) ) {
    $folder.Title  # Output localized title
}
```

- [`[Environment]::GetFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=net-6.0#system-environment-getfolderpath(system-environment-specialfolder)) gives us the filesystem path of a system folder.
- The [`Shell.Namespace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-namespace) function returns a [`Folder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder) object corresponding to this path which can be queried for its localized name.
- The alternative shows how you can get the localized name more directly, by passing an enumeration value of [`[Environment+SpecialFolder]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-6.0) to the `Shell.Namespace()` function.
- When passing a path to the `Shell.Namespace()` method, it works for **any folder customized via "desktop.ini"**, even if it's not a system folder.

Comment: Hi zett42, thanks for the fast and good response. I will vote it up once I am able to. Nevertheless, by the answer I see that I should have given more than only one example.  It works perfectly fine for folders in the Shell namespace, but probably not for singular files/links that are localized by a LocalizedResourceName in desktop.ini, right? Or did I overlook something in your answer?

Comment: @WolfgangPohl It does work with _any_ folder that is customized via "desktop.ini". I just copied a "desktop.ini" from my documents folder to "C:\Test", applied it using `attrib +s` and now `$shell.Namespace('C:\Test').Title` outputs as expected.

Comment: Hi zett42, thanks again. Probably, I have overlooked that in the documentation. I will give it a try tonight, and let you know the outcome.

Comment: Hi @zett42, I tried it and it works for any folders customized by a desktop.ini, but unfortunately, not for files localized by the LocalFileNames section in the desktop.ini.

Comment: @WolfgangPohl `LocalFileNames` is new to me, I will research this if I find some time. I would be surprised if there is something shell-related that can't be automated, given the rich interface that the shell provides.

Comment: @WolfgangPohl Did a quick search, couldn't find anything about `LocalFileNames` section. Can you give me a pointer or add an example to your question?

Comment: Apologies for the typo, the section is named **LocalizedFileNames**.